# Error creating file using new File(directory).mkdir()

Tags: java, file

I used `new File(directory).mkdir()` to create a new folder.

When i set
`directory = "C:\\Users\\livw\\Desktop\New folder\\5b27233480c016706f62a30a"`,

it works.

But when i add one more child folder to the directory: 
`directory = "C:\\Users\\livw\\Desktop\\New folder\\5b27233480c016706f62a30a\\Samples"`,
it doesn't create the folder.

How can i fix it?

Comment: Does `C:\\Users\\livw\\Desktop\New folder\\5b27233480c016706f62a30a` exist BEFORE hand? (and is `5b27233480c016706f62a30a` a directory and not a file?)

Comment: use mkdirs() instead of mkdir(), unlike mkdir() ,  mkdirs() garauntees the creation of any non existing parent directories also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short and sweet,

Use mkdirs() instead of mkdir().

## Hope it helps

Please in future refer to documentation.

Comment: It worked. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: @TanNguyen if it helped then you could mark this as an accepted answer this helps the community to help others.

Comment: Yes, i'm waiting to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

directory = "C:\Users\livw\Desktop\New folder\5b27233480c016706f62a30a"
kindly check the directory address as file separator is not properly given before new Folder

```
import java.io.File;`
public class FileCreation {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new  File("C:\\Users\\Master\\Desktop\\Horse\\demo\\devil").mkdir();
        new File("C:\\Users\\Master\\Desktop\\Horse\\demo\\devil"+File.separator+"a").mkdir();
    }
}
```